# How to remove dd-wrt from a router

Tags: router, wireless-router, dd-wrt

I have a Netgear WNR2000v3. I have flashed dd-wrt to the router and now want to remove it. I can access dd-wrt via WiFi but I can not access it via a lan port. I have attempted many 30-30-30 resets and tried to use tftp2 to flash it with no results. Is there any way I could restore this router to the default netgear firmware? If any one wants to know why I am removing dd-wrt it is because it will now work. No matter what I do I can not get internet access. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can restore the default netgear firmware through this

http://support.netgear.com/product/WNR2000v3#wrapper

(It has the netgear firmware, which you i suppose that you can flash your router to)